# Vue js does not re-render the page height after routing to another page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, routes, router, vue-router

Hello dear developers!

I am new to Vue.js and I am struggling now on one visual issue.
While navigating the user from **navbar** to the previous page via `<b-dropdown-item @click="go_login">Login</b-dropdown-item>` where **go_login()** =

`go_login: function () {
      this.$router.push('/login')
 }`

the page routes to the **login** component but the height of the page do not update. This does not happen if you use `href="/login"` instead or type the adress directly in the browser adress bar but i do not want (would not like) to use `href`.

What am I missing?

My code:

**router/index.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import store from '../store/store'
import userLogin from '../views/userLoginPage'
import landingPage from '../views/landingPage'
import admin from '../views/admin'
import userRegistration from '../views/userRegistration'
import userPasswordReset from '../views/userPasswordReset'
import pageNotFound from '../views/404'
import userProfile from '../views/userProfile'

Vue.use(Router)

// checks if user is authenticated and allowed to se the page
const ifAuthenticated = (to, from, next) => {
  if (store.getters.isAuthenticated) {
    next()
    return
  }
  next('/login')
}

/**
 * icon names can be found on fontawesome page
 * for example https://fontawesome.com/icons/volume-up?style=solid
 */
export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'landingPage',
      component: landingPage,
      props: {msg: 'Welcome to Tonefeed!', icon: 'volume-up'}
    },
    {
      path: '/login',
      name: 'userLogin',
      component: userLogin,
      props: {msg: 'Sign in', icon: 'key'}
    },
    {
      path: '/profile',
      name: 'userLProfile',
      component: userProfile,
      props: {msg: 'Profile', icon: 'user'},
      beforeEnter: ifAuthenticated
    },

    // for testing purposes guests are not allowed to see this page
    {
      path: '/admin',
      name: 'bootstrapExamples',
      component: admin,
      props: {msg: 'Admin', icon: 'user-ninja'},
      beforeEnter: ifAuthenticated
    },
    {
      path: '/register',
      name: 'register',
      component: userRegistration,
      props: {msg: 'Registration', icon: 'pen-alt'}
    },
    {
      path: '/password-reset',
      name: 'userPasswordReset',
      component: userPasswordReset,
      props: {msg: 'Password reset', icon: 'unlock'}
    },
    {
      path: '/404',
      name: 'pageNotFound',
      component: pageNotFound,
      props: {msg: '404', icon: 'exclamation-triangle'}
    },
    // if url is unknown => redirect to 404
    {
      path: '*',
      redirect: '/404'
    }
  ],
  scrollBehavior (to, from, savedPosition) {
    return { x: 0, y: 0 }
  }
})
```

**components/navigationBar.vue**

```
<template>
  <b-navbar :class="{'classA navbar-dark': scrollPosition < 64, 'classB navbar-light': scrollPosition > 64}"
            toggleable="md">

    <b-navbar-toggle target="nav_collapse"></b-navbar-toggle>

    <b-navbar-brand>
      <font-awesome-icon :icon="icon"></font-awesome-icon>
      Tonefeed
    </b-navbar-brand>

    <b-collapse is-nav id="nav_collapse">

      <b-navbar-nav>
        <b-nav-item>Column 1</b-nav-item>
        <b-nav-item>Column 2</b-nav-item>
      </b-navbar-nav>

      <!-- Right aligned nav items -->
      <b-navbar-nav class="ml-auto">

        <b-nav-form>
          <b-form-input size="sm" class="mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search"/>
          <button
            :class="{'button btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm': scrollPosition < 64, 'button btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm': scrollPosition > 64}">
            Search
          </button>
        </b-nav-form>

        <b-nav-item-dropdown text="Lang" right>
          <b-dropdown-item>EN</b-dropdown-item>
          <b-dropdown-item>DE</b-dropdown-item>
          <b-dropdown-item href="/login">RU</b-dropdown-item>
        </b-nav-item-dropdown>

        <b-nav-item-dropdown text="User" right>
          <b-dropdown-item @click="go_profile">Profile</b-dropdown-item>
          <b-dropdown-item @click="go_home">Logout</b-dropdown-item>
          <b-dropdown-item @click="go_login">Login</b-dropdown-item>
          <b-dropdown-item @click="go_register">Register</b-dropdown-item>
        </b-nav-item-dropdown>
      </b-navbar-nav>

    </b-collapse>
  </b-navbar>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'navBar',
  data () {
    return {
      scrolled: false,
      scrollPosition: null
    }
  },
  props: {
    icon: String
  },
  methods: {
    go_login: function () {
      this.$router.push('/login')
    },
    go_home: function () {
      this.$store.dispatch('AUTH_LOGOUT')
        .then(() => {
          this.$router.push('/')
        })
    },
    go_register: function () {
      this.$router.push('/register')
    },
    go_profile: function () {
      this.$router.push('/profile')
    },
    handleScroll () {
      this.scrolled = window.scrollY > 0
      this.scrollPosition = window.scrollY
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll)
  },
  destroy () {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll)
  }
}
</script>

<style>
  .classA.navbar-dark {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    background: transparent;
    transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  }

  .classB.navbar-light {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    background: white;
    transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  }

  .topnav a:hover {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
  }
</style>
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div>
      <navigationBar v-bind:icon="icon"></navigationBar>
    </div>
    <div id="app" class="container">
      <router-view :key="$route.fullPath"></router-view>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import navigationBar from './components/navigationBar'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  data () {
    return {
      icon: 'volume-up'
    }
  },
  components: {
    navigationBar: navigationBar
  },
  // if token expires the user should log out
  created: function () {
    this.axios.interceptors.response.use(undefined, function (err) {
      return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        if (err.status === 401 && err.config && !err.config.__isRetryRequest) {
          // if you ever get an unauthorized, logout the user
          this.$store.dispatch('AUTH_LOGOUT')
          // you can also redirect to /login if needed !
        }
        throw err
      })
    })
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss">
  @import './styles/custom-bootstrap.scss';
  @import '../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';

  body {
    background: url("./assets/overlay2.png"), url("./assets/overlay3.svg");
    background-position: top left, center center;
    background-size: auto, cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
  }

  .container-fluid{
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  #app {
    padding-top: 4rem;
  }

  a, a:hover {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem you're facing is due to the fact that the page doesn't get refreshed when you use: (As it is a Single Page Application)

```
this.$router.push('/login')
```

When you use href to navigate it refreshes the whole content of the page and same is the case with entering the url directly.

So in order to make the component take the actual width and height you should use:

```
location.reload(); // in the components life cycle hook
```

Please tell if this worked for you.

Comment: Glad to help you. :)